# SQL Writing the average wage

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

He wants to write departments and their average wages, in which employees currently earn over 8,000

I tried this way but it shows 
- 1111 - Invalid use of group function

```
ELECT departments.dept_name, AVG(salaries.salary) FROM departments, salaries 
INNER JOIN employees ON salaries.emp_no = employees.emp_no 
INNER JOIN dept_manager ON employees.emp_no = dept_manager.emp_no 
INNER JOIN dept_emp ON departments.dept_no = dept_emp.emp_no
WHERE AVG(salaries.salary)>8000
```

And

List all employees who have the same name as employees
between 1/01/0985 and 1/02/1985.

```
SELECT  emp_no, first_name
    FROM  employees AS pole1
    WHERE  EXISTS (
        SELECT  pole2.emp_no
            FROM  employees AS pole2, salaries
            WHERE  pole1.first_name = pole2.first_name
              AND  pole1.emp_no <> pole2.emp_no
              AND  salaries.from_date BETWEEN 01-01-1985 AND 01-02-1985 
                  )
```

This query does not want to be done

Comment: Do you know the difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately

Comment: `WHERE` is used to determine which rows to include in the result set. `AVG()` is calculated over all the rows in the result set. How can you use the result set in deciding which rows to include? Isn't it obviously backwards?

Comment: When I used HEAVE, it shortened 0 lines

Comment: you need to use having clause

Comment: Alex T can u help me?

Comment: SELECT departments.dept_name 
FROM (departments, salaries, dept_emp)
JOIN departments ON  dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
GROUP BY departments.dept_name
HAVING AVG(salaries.salary)>=ALL
(SELECT  AVG(salary) FROM salaries WHERE AVG(salaty)>8000 GROUP BY emp_no)

Comment: Dates are in the format yyyy-mm-dd; they won't compare correctly with what you have.